# Displaying ComboBox

Tags: c++, winapi, combobox

I have problem with displaying Combobox and another controls in WinApi. I tried to create c++ classes which could help me in creating my applications.
Each class contains one control and basic operations.
So I create main WinApiElement.h class:

```
#pragma once

#include <windows.h>

class WinApiElement
{
public:
    virtual LRESULT CALLBACK InteriorWndProc(HWND hwnd,UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) = 0;
    static LRESULT CALLBACK StaticWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    HWND handle;
};
```

Where staticWndProc receive Messages and direct them into `InteriorWndProc` (using GWLP_USERDATA). Class component inherits class `WinApiElement`, and contain basic operations:

```
#pragma once

#include <Windows.h>
#include <Windowsx.h>
#include "WinApiElement.h"
#include "Application.h"
#include "Define.h"

...

class Component : public WinApiElement
{

protected:
    int x;
    int y;
    int width;
    int height;
    int componentNumber;
    bool transparent;
    bool mouseHover;
    bool LButtonDown;
    TRACKMOUSEEVENT trackMouse;

    void Create(WinApiElement* Parent, DWORD dwExStyle, LPCSTR nComponent, DWORD ndwStyle, bool parentWndProc, int nleft = 0, int ntop = 0, int nwidth = 200, int nheight = 100);
    virtual void WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
public:
    LRESULT CALLBACK InteriorWndProc(HWND hwnd,UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) override;

    Component(WinApiElement* Parent, DWORD dwExStyle, LPCSTR nComponent, DWORD ndwStyle, bool parentWndProc, int nleft = 0, int ntop = 0, int nwidth = 200, int nheight = 100);
    ~Component();

    WinApiElement* parent;

    bool setPosition(int newX, int newY);
    bool setSize(int newWidth, int newHeight);
    bool setLocation(int newX, int newY, int newWidth, int newHeight);

    int getX();
    bool setX(int newX);
    int getY();
    bool setY(int newY);
    int getWidth();
    bool setWidth(int Width);
    int getHeight();
    bool setHeight(int Height);

    void setTransparent(bool newTransparent);
    void Repaint();
    // Components control metods
    virtual void OnResize();
    virtual void OnMouseMove(int moveX, int moveY);
    virtual void OnMouseLeftDown();
    virtual void OnMouseRightDown();
    virtual void OnPaint();
    virtual void OnMouseEnter();
    virtual void OnMouseLeave();
    virtual void OnLeftButtonHoldDown();
    // -------------------------

    void Show(bool value);

    void setBorder(bool value);

    bool Refresh();

    virtual void OnPaint(HWND handle, HDC hdc);
};
```

Main function in this class is Create because it set WndProc and UserData.

```
void Component::Create(WinApiElement* Parent, DWORD dwExStyle, LPCSTR nComponent, DWORD ndwStyle, bool parentWndProc, int nleft, int ntop, int nwidth, int nheight)
{
    componentNumber = Application::AddComponent();
    uindex = componentNumber;
    handle = CreateWindowEx(dwExStyle , nComponent, NULL, ndwStyle ,nleft,ntop,nwidth,nheight, Parent->handle, (HMENU) componentNumber, Application::GetInstance(), NULL);

    parent = Parent;

    wndProc = (LONG_PTR)StaticWndProc;// else wndProc = (LONG_PTR)Parent->StaticWndProc; 
    transparent = false;
    SetLastError(0);

    SetWindowLongPtr( handle, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)wndProc);
    if(!(GetLastError() == 0))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,"Nie udało się zmienić standardowej funkcji obsługi rozkazu dla kontrolki, nie wszystkie funkcje moga działać poprawnie!","Błąd przy tworzenia komponentu",MB_ICONWARNING);
    }   

    SetLastError(0);    
    SetWindowLongPtr( handle , GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)((WinApiElement*)this) );
    if(!(GetLastError() == 0))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,"Nie udało się zmienić wskaźnika w komponencie w funkcji setTransparent, nie wszystkie funkcje moga działać poprawnie!","Błąd przy zmienia parametru transparent komponentu",MB_ICONWARNING);
    }

    SetWindowPos(handle,HWND_TOP,0,0,0,0,SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);

    x = nleft;
    y = ntop;
    width = nwidth;
    height = nheight;
    Refresh();
}
```

And a simply Combobox class.

```
#pragma once

#include <Windows.h>
#include "Component.h"
#include "WinApiElement.h"

class Combobox : public Component
{
public:
    Combobox(WinApiElement* Parent);
    void AddItem(LPCSTR item);
};
```

And now the problem: When I run this code the Combobox is not displaying. But when I don't set WndProc and UserData everythink is ok but it doesn't satisfy me.

@ edit

So here is my StaticWndProc function code

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WinApiElement::StaticWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // Recover the pointer to our class, don't forget to type cast it back

    WinApiElement* winptr = (WinApiElement*)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA);
    // Check if the pointer is NULL and call the Default WndProc

    if (winptr == NULL) 
    {

        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    } 
    else 
    {
        // Call the Message Handler for my class (MsgProc in my case)
        return winptr->InteriorWndProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam); 
    }
}
```

And InteriorWndproc where method wndProc is execute. It's look's strange but InteriorWndProc supports standard Component's messages and method WndProc is diffrent for each control.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK Component::InteriorWndProc(HWND hwnd,UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(uMsg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            break;

        case WM_SIZE:
            OnResize();     
            break;

        case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
            POINT pt;
            pt.x = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
            pt.y = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);

            OnMouseMove(pt.x,pt.y);

            if(LButtonDown) OnLeftButtonHoldDown();

            if(!mouseHover)
            {
                SetTimer(handle,TID_POLLMOUSE,MOUSE_POLL_DELAY,NULL);
                OnMouseEnter();
                mouseHover = true;
            }
            break;

        case WM_TIMER:
            if(mouseHover)
            {
                RECT rc;
                GetWindowRect(handle,&rc);
                GetCursorPos(&pt);
                if(!PtInRect(&rc,pt))
                {
                    KillTimer(handle,TID_POLLMOUSE);
                    OnMouseLeave();
                    mouseHover = false;
                    LButtonDown = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;

        case WM_PAINT:
            OnPaint();
            break;

        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
            OnMouseLeftDown();
            if(transparent)
            {
                ((Component*)parent)->OnMouseLeftDown();
            }
            if(!LButtonDown)
            {
                OnLeftButtonHoldDown();
                LButtonDown = true;
            }
            break;

        case WM_LBUTTONUP:
            LButtonDown = false;
            break;

        case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
            OnMouseRightDown();
            break;

        case WM_COMMAND:

            break;
    }

    WndProc(hwnd,uMsg,wParam,lParam);

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd,uMsg,wParam,lParam);
}
```

Comment: Then presumably you are not correctly forwarding one or more messages in WndProc. Certain replies are mandatory; you cannot simply ignore everything and return zero. For any message you do not handle, call the global dispatcher. For any message you do handle, study the API reference carefully to see what response is expected.

Comment: The important part is the code for the window procedures, `InteriorWndProc` and `StaticWndProc`. You should post that.

Comment: Your code is defective, but only you can see it. Why didn't you post a [mcve] so that we can see it too?

Comment: I have just added this 2 functions. I have to read really good book about Winapi.

Comment: And thanks for all answers :)